# Setting up Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot with preinstalled Windows 7 without Windows CD

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I don't have the Windows CD with me, and I don't mind making and using the Ubuntu CD, but Windows 7 is already installed on my computer.
Now I want to get Ubuntu so that I can have the Ubuntu + Windows 7 dual boot option on boot.
What should I do? Does [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) fulfill my needs? If I must have a Windows 7 CD, what kind of CD do I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

The UbuntuLive CD which you can download from the [Ubuntu Website](http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) will give you the option of installing alongside your existing Windows 7 installation without damaging it.

***It's always good to back up your data files, just in case anything goes wrong!***

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Windows disk to install Ubuntu.

1. download the Ubuntu **64bit** image from http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
2. either burn it on a DVD (not a CD), or on a USB disk (via UnetBootIn or LiliUSB)
3. Reboot your computer on this Ubuntu disk
4. install Ubuntu [the standard way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)
5. if any issue, follow [these advice for UEFI systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)